# How to implement bundle diameter calculation algorithm for different wire sizes?

Tags: c#, .net

My apologies that I have not come up with a better way to ask this question. Basically, I see some software that implement an algorithm to calculate the bundle diameter as shown in picture below. Assume that a list of individual wire outside diameter is given and cross-section copper can be ignored. How can I implement something similar? I am looking for numerical solution and graphical if possible.

The position of each wire is not important as long as it is inside of the bundle diameter.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: @Felix I think after more than 8 years on SO the OP should know that

Comment: So the question is "what's the minimum inside diameter circle that can contain N smaller circles of diameter D?" Is that correct. That abounds like a problem that has been solved. Try searching around for different phrasing of your question. An algorithm will likely turn up. FWIW, this question is better tagged `algorithm`. It really has nothing to do with `c#` or `.net`

Comment: I would not be sure an optimal polynomial algorithm exist for arbitrary mixes of wire diameters. So you might need to use some heuristics.

Comment: Is the question "what's the minimum inside diameter circle that can contain N smaller circles of diameter D?" as indicated by @Flydog57 or is it "what's the minimum inside diameter circle that can contain N smaller circles of *different diameters*" ?